# file_get_contents and simplexml_load_file are empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to read the xml from this url:

> https://username:password@wetter.ws.siag.it/Weather_V1.svc/web/getLastProvBulletin?lang=de

but even when I try it with simplexml_load_file($url) I get this error:

> parser error : Document is empty

And when I want to test it with file_get_contents($url) i get an empty string

> ""

Is it possible that this website blocks scripts? When yes, why it works with the wordpressplugin **WP All import**

I also tried it with curl:

```
private function curl($url) {
        $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
        $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
        $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
        $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
        $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";


        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;
    }
```

... same issue

Comment: Some scripts require a user agent-header to be set. That's just an example, though. It's impossible for us to know why this is, since we don't have any information about the source or how WP is doing the request. Have you checked that your php.ini has `allow_url_fopen` set to true?

Comment: i edited my question - i also tryed it with curl and set headers... yes allow_url_fopen is On

Comment: Try this before you close curl: `$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` and see what the http code is. It might give you a clue?

Comment: Remove the username and password from the URL (`https://wetter.ws.siag.it/Weather_V1.svc/web/getLastProvBulletin?lang=de`) and send the auth in the header instead: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);`. Does that work?

Comment: When tested with the above URL, it returns 0 for me as well, but if I change to `http` instead of `https`, I get a status code (can't get the body since I don't have any real credentials).